# Is it possible to insert the data inside sharedpreference into mysql database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, insert, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to insert the data inside `SharedPreferences` into remote MySQL database? Say i will insert a product for a specific user that is logged in or maybe you know a better way doing that. I am using `SharedPreferences` for my login session.

If you know a tutorial about that please kindly share, i need it in my project and i am new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

**First**: retrieve the data from the `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this);
Integer myValue = sp.getInt("myKey", 0);
```

**Then:** insert the returned value into your database:

This tutorial shows how to perform an INSERT into a MySQL database: http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php

Hope it helps.